# Is it possible to send a variable to a thread every time a button is pressed in winforms?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am somewhat beginner to C# and writing a code to acquire data from FPGA with USB communication. Data is continuously received only when `DOPPLER_NUM = 1`, and that process is executed in an independent thread `Doppler_loop`. Every time I pressed `Doppler_Start` button, `Doppler_loop` thread should start and stop reapeatedly since `DOPLLER_NUM` changes. But this does not work. I found that `DOPPLER_NUM` in UI thread changes, but it does not seem to be passed to loop thread because the loop while loop does not stop.

Following is the main thread

```
int DOPPLER_NUM = 0;

private void Doppler_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
     int transmit_mode = 1; 

     if (DOPPLER_NUM == 0)
     {
          DOPPLER_NUM = 1;
     }
     else
     {
          DOPPLER_NUM = 0;
          cnt4GS = 0;
     }

     CyBulkEndPoint Inednpt1;
     Inednpt1 = MyDevice.EndPointOf(0x86) as CyBulkEndPoint;

     int bytes1 = Convert.ToInt32(256);
     int bytes2 = bytes1 * 2;

     bool bXferCompleted = false;

     bool IsPkt = false;

     Thread loop = new Thread( () => Doppler_loop(DOPPLER_NUM, MyDevice, Inednpt1) );

     loop.Start();
    
       }
```

And this is code for loop thread.

```
 public void Doppler_loop(int DOPPLER_NUM, CyUSBDevice MyDevice, CyBulkEndPoint Inednpt1)
        {
            byte[] buffer1 = new byte[512];
            byte[] Data_buf = new byte[256];
            byte[] buffer4GS = new byte[400 * 256]; // buf_Width = 400, buf_Height = 256

            int bytes2 = Convert.ToInt32(512);

            bool bXferCompleted = false;

            while (DOPPLER_NUM == 1)
            {

                if (MyDevice != null && Inednpt1 != null)
                {
                    bXferCompleted = Inednpt1.XferData(ref buffer1, ref bytes2, false);

                    double fft_dv1 = (double)(buffer1[2] % 16);
                    double fft_dv2 = (double)(buffer1[4] % 16);

                    if (fft_dv1 != 15 && fft_dv2 != 15)
                    {
                        Data_buf = Doppler_Processing(buffer1, 512);


                        if (cnt4GS >= 0 && cnt4GS <= 399)
                        {
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(Data_buf, 0, buffer4GS, cnt4GS * 256, 256);

                            cnt4GS++;
                        }
                        else if (cnt4GS >= 400)
                        {
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer4GS, 256, buffer4GS, 0, 102144);
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(Data_buf, 0, buffer4GS, 102144, 256);
                        }

                        Grayscale(buffer4GS);
                        
                    }                    
                }
                else if (MyDevice == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR. NODEVICE.", "Error Message");
                    break;
                }                               
            }
        }
```

```
private void Grayscale(byte[] buf)
        {
            int buf_Width = 256;
            int buf_Height = 400;

            // Create a new bitmap
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(buf_Width, buf_Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

            System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette pal = bmp.Palette;

            // Create grayscale palette
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb((int)255, i, i, i);
            }

            // Assign to bmp
            bmp.Palette = pal;

            // Lock it to get the BitmapDatat objet
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

            // Copy the bytes
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(buf, 0, bmData.Scan0, bmData.Stride * bmData.Height);

            // Never forget to unlock the bitmap
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);

            bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX);

            // Display
            if (Doppler.InvokeRequired)
            {
                Doppler.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.Doppler.Image = bmp; }));
            }
            else
            {
                this.Doppler.Image = bmp;
            }            
        }
```

I tried to stop loop thread via `loop.Abort()`, but it does not work. And I am not sure which one is more beneficial in terms of memory, stopping the loop thread or sending `DOPPLER_NUM` variable to the loop thread.

Comment: You pass the current value of the DOPPLER_NUM field to the thread. The value of the parameter DOPPLER_NUM in Doppler_loop is therefore fixed. You might remove this parameter fro the method so that you reference the DOPPLER_NUM field instead.

Comment: I normally worry some when I see *I am somewhat beginner to C#* and *executed in an independent thread* in close proximity. Multi threading is hard to organize and typically unnecessary